# Criar dialogo no Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou tentando criar um dialogo para remover um cliente no Django (Criei o dialogo com o Materialize), porém ao tentar remover não executa a função da view dentro da página html. Alguém poderia ajudar?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

delete

```
        <!-- Modal Structure -->
        <div id="modal1" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Deseja remover o Cliente {{ Cliente.nome_cliente }}?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button name="remover_cliente" type="submit" class="modal-close btn light-blue lighten">Remover</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'listar_cliente' %}" class="modal-close btn light-blue lighten">Voltar</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def remover_cliente(request, pk):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        cliente.delete()
        return redirect('listar_cliente')
    return render(request, {'cliente': cliente})
```

Comment: Tinha pensado nisso mas não sabia se estava correto. Agora já sei como fazer, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O teu formulário não está invocando o método da *view*, daí ele não executa a tarefa. Você se esqueceu de colocar o `action="{% url 'remover_cliente' %}"` dentro da *tag* `form`.